# How to create Bootstrap Collapsible Panels with full width content without collapsing other columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a responsive grid to displays items that show details when clicked, I can get it to expand but my problem is the elements next to the one clicked collapses down the expanded content and I don't want that, I want to keep all the items at the top and have the content expanded below

Here is what I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#toggleDemo").collapse('toggle');
});
 $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#toggleDemo2").collapse('toggle');
});
 $("#btn3").click(function(){
    $("#toggleDemo3").collapse('toggle');
});});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bs-example">
<!-- Trigger Button HTML -->
<input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Toggle Button">
  <div id="toggleDemo" class="collapse in"><p>This is a simple example of expanding and collapsing individual element via JavaScript. </div>
<input type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary" value="Toggle Button 2">
  <div id="toggleDemo2" class="collapse in"><p>This is a simple example of expanding and collapsing individual element via JavaScript.</div>
<input type="button" id="btn3" class="btn btn-primary" value="Toggle Button 3">
<!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
<div id="toggleDemo3" class="collapse in"><p>This is a simple example of expanding and collapsing individual element via JavaScript. </div>
```

Please if you have any idea on how to acomplish it I'd apreciate it

Comment: Plz give a fiddle demo

Comment: Here is Raviteja demo http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/ft4mnynh/2/ you can read my reply on why that doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You don't even need JavaScript

```
<div>
<input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" value="Toggle Button">
<input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" value="Toggle Button 2">
<input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" value="Toggle Button 3">
</div>      

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    content
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
    content 2
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
    content 3
</div>
```

[**Demo in fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/ft4mnynh/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it is not 100% what I need because when seen on mobile the contents will show below all buttons and not below each one, this is a problem because I want to use images instead of buttons and also add 5 elements per row, user would have to scroll down too far to see the content

Comment: Then how do you need ?

Comment: I need that when displayed on mobile each content stays below its button, not below all buttons

Comment: How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/o3479Lf9/4/).Still without javascript

Comment: That's how I want it to look on mobile but I need 5 columns on wide screens

Comment: Then that could be another question.

Comment: You got it better on this one but still not full width content, Krish's answer seems to be the best right now. I admit my question may not be so clear and I apologize for that, thank you for your time

Comment: I'm afraid It's not, I need it to display full width content in all screen sizes, like @Krish did

Comment: It is(krish's) overlapping on medium screen if you observe.Try to open two  contents which are one over the other

Comment: I don't understand the last thing you said, maybe if you can, post an image or something

Comment: Click every button to open the content and change the window size.You'll see the issue.

Comment: Get it, I think I'll change it to only allow one open at a time

Comment: In fact you are right, It causes a bigger problem, when I add more buttons that create a new row, content overlaps on the buttons

Answer (score 0):

This can make with custom Jquery code instead of bootstrap. check below codes

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
      $(this).next('.collapse').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="collapses-panel">
  <input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" value="Toggle Button">

  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    content
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" value="Toggle Button">
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
    content 2
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="btn3" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" value="Toggle Button">

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
  content 3
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.collapses-panel {
  position: relative;
}
.btn-primary{
  display: block;
}
.collapse {
  display: none;
  background-color: gray;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .collapse {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .btn-primary{
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/ft4mnynh/7/

Comment: This is great, thank you Krish, what if I want to show 3 columns on wide screens, 2 columns on medium and 1 column on small?

Comment: Updated answer doesn't display full width content and I really need it because I'll have rows with at least 5 elements

Comment: Also, on the first answer when I add more buttons that create a new row, content overlaps on the buttons